# How to use setInterval on arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
  function rotateElement1() {
    let n1 = parseFloat(document.querySelectorAll('.rotateElementInput')[0].value);
    let n2 = parseFloat(document.querySelectorAll('.rotateElementInput')[1].value);
    let n3 = parseFloat(document.querySelectorAll('.rotateElementInput')[2].value);
    document.getElementById('rotateElementR').innerHTML = rotateElement2(n1, n2, n3);
  }
  function rotateElement2(n1, n2, n3) {
        let arr = [n1, n2, n3];
      var timer = setInterval(function() {
        let lastItem = arr.pop();
        let addToStart = arr.unshift(lastItem);
        return arr;
      }, 1000);  
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" class="rotateElementInput" value="1">
<input type="number" class="rotateElementInput" value="2">
<input type="number" class="rotateElementInput" value="3">
<button onclick="rotateElement1()">Try</button>
<div id="rotateElementR"></div>
```

```js
function rotateElement2() {
      var timer = setInterval(function() {
        let arr = [1, 2, 3];
        let lastItem = arr.pop();
        let addToStart = arr.unshift(lastItem);
        document.getElementById('rotateElementR').innerHTML = arr;
      }, 1000);
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="rotateElement2()">Try</button>
<div id="rotateElementR"></div>
```

(This is a new question)In the code above, I want to rotate the items inside the array. I mean the last item comes first every second in the array. I used setInterval but it does not work. If i remove  `return` keyword and set  `document.getElementById('rotateElementR').innerHTML = arr;` it works.

Comment: Well does not help when you redeclare your array every time setInterval is called.... Move it outside the interval

Answer (score 1):

Because you redeclare the array on every iteration of the interval of it is always the default

```
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
     let arr = [1, 2, 3];  <-- you define it ever time
```

You need to move it outside of it

```js
function rotateElement2() {
  let arr = [1, 2, 3];
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    let lastItem = arr.pop();
    let addToStart = arr.unshift(lastItem);
    document.getElementById('rotateElementR').innerHTML = arr;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="rotateElement2()">Try</button>
<div id="rotateElementR"></div>
```

Comment: And that really should be a different question..... You should not ask a question and edit it with a new one that changes the functionality.

Comment: Should i ask a new question?